# Finding correlation of two data variables, matlab (Concept)

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

I have a very large data.Its  too big to post here. So really don't have idea how to ask this question? I'm using matlab.

```
mat = [time_days temperature, change_in_mm] %
```

[image]

[image]

I want to find cross-correlation between temperature & change_in_mm with respect to time.

Basic idea is to do it in frequency domain.

```
f_data = fft(t_data, N)
```

1. How should I select *N*?
2. Should I convert both temperature & change_in_mm into frequency domain?

There should be relation between `temperature` and `change_in_mm`. I want to see that correlation between `temperature` and `change_in_mm` during winter and summer as well as over day and night.

What should be my next steps?Can any body guide me in this regard.

%----------------------Edited-----------------------------------%

I tried it already but can't understand the meaning of graph.

```
R=xcorr(temperature, change_in_mm);
N = length(temperature); %// or N = length(change_in_mm)
R = R(N + 1:end);

figure;
plot(R,'r')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have the [Signal Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/signal/) installed, save yourself some trouble and use [`xcorr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html):

```
R = xcorr(temperature, change_in_mm);
```

The length of the resulting vector `R` is `length(temperature) + length(change_in_mm) - 1`. Perhaps you might be interested only in the positive lags, so you should consider trimming the output and keep only the second half:

```
R = R((length(temperature) + length(change_in_mm))/2:end);
```

or in case they both contain the same number of samples:

```
N = length(temperature); %// or N = length(change_in_mm)
R = R(N + 1:end);
```

Comment: @ Eithan, please see edited. But I want in frequency domain also.